# Sendmail, is possible to verify the sender?

Tags: sendmail

I'm testing my sendmail server, i tried it for openrelay

```
telnet sendmailserver 25

mail from: fake@fake.priv
250 2.1.0 fake@fake.priv... Sender ok
rcpt to: user@true.blue.priv
550 5.7.1 user@true.blue.priv... Relaying denied. Proper authentication required.
```

good, seems is not open-relay

But I can fake my address

```
telnet sendmailserver 25

mail from: fake@fake.priv
250 2.1.0 fake@fake.priv... Sender ok
rcpt to: user@server.blue.priv
250 2.1.5 user@server.blue.priv... Recipient ok
data
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
Hi i'm fake user
.
250 2.0.0 13PETO7j015523 Message accepted for delivery
```

The question is simple: is possible to block the "fake user" and force it to use is real email address?

Comment: Are you receiving mails through sendmail package?

Comment: yes, works fine